# Angular JS: Failed to instantiate module myApp

Tags: angularjs

i was testing a small angular directives code then i got the error by firebug console that **Failed to instantiate module myApp**

see and tell me what is wrong in the above code

```
  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div log='some-div'></div>
    <p>Have a look at you console!</p>
  </div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('log', function() {

  return {
    controller: function( $scope, $attrs ) {
      console.log( $attrs.log + ' (controller)' );
    },
    compile: function compile( tElement, tAttributes ) {
      console.log( tAttributes.log + ' (compile)'  );
      return {
        pre: function preLink( scope, element, attributes ) {
          console.log( attributes.log + ' (pre-link)'  );
        },
        post: function postLink( scope, element, attributes ) {
          console.log( attributes.log + ' (post-link)'  );
        }
      };
    }
  };

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why but your fiddle code doesn't work. Used same code in my fiddle and it works

https://jsfiddle.net/sathvike/e7vkqxs8/

If you use this code in your fiddle it works

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
    <div log='some-div'></div>
    <p>Have a look at you console!</p>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
 myApp.directive('log', function() {

 return {
     controller: function($scope, $attrs) {
     console.log($attrs.log + ' (controller)');
  },
  compile: function(tElement, tAttributes) {
    console.log(tAttributes.log + ' (compile)');
    return {
      pre: function preLink(scope, element, attributes) {
        console.log(attributes.log + ' (pre-link)');
      },
      post: function postLink(scope, element, attributes) {
        console.log(attributes.log + ' (post-link)');
      }
    };
  }
  };

 }); 
</script>
```

Comment: what was the difference between your code and mine ?

Comment: Not sure why, I also added external reference to angularjs library but it didn't work. Sorry can't explain exactly why.

Answer (score 2):

Where it says 
`compile: function compile( tElement, tAttributes ) {`

I think it should say
`compile: function( tElement, tAttributes ) {`

Same difference at the pre: and post: functions a bit further down.

Edit: Your real issue is that your last line needs to invoke the function like so:
`})();`

Comment: still getting same error "Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument."